# Scala: Using the App trait

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I have an app that extends App and a trait that implements an option parser. All the trait needs is that some class or trait in the runtime mix provides:

```
val args: Array[String]
```

If I declare:

```
trait OptionParser extends App {...}
```

All is fine but that rules out any other use of the option parser than with an App object. Not sure if there are inefficiencies in having the app extend App as well as mixing in OptionParser as with:

```
object MyApp extends App with OptionParser {...}
```

I realize this could be shortened to:

```
object MyApp extends OptionParser {...}
```

But ideally I'd like to make OptionParser completely independent except for relying on  `args` to be provided and this is only because that's where App puts them.

Is there some way to declare a dependency without providing the class or trait to take it from? An error could be detected at link time so as not to break type safety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do.  How about that:

```
trait OptionParser {
  protected def args: Array[String]

}
```

This way, you can mixin `OptionParser` with anything that provides a `args`, not necessarily `App`.

Edit:  since `App` defines `args` visibility as `protected` you need to do that in `OptionParser` as well. This is unfortunate.  Here is another idea:

```
trait OptionParser {def options: Array[String] ... }
```

object MyApp extends App with OptionParser {def options = args ...}

Comment: Exactly, so any args access by any mix-ins will get the same identical args object? This is done by name and type alone? Cool.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Basically what the `OptionParser` is saying is "I will work just fine as long as you mix me with something that will provide me with a member called `args` of type `Array[String]`." Then it's totally up to you to decide how you provide it.  For your case, you mix in `OptionParser` with `App` which does provide a concrete value for `args`.

Comment: You are right in this case. Using `protected` will work but this is a bit unfortunate.  See my edit for another option.

Comment: Assignment to options in the constructor of the extending object is a bit hidden--with no compile time error. Defining args in the trait would be a compile time error, which I prefer in this case. Obscure runtime trait dependencies on constructors are often hard to track down and an unfortunate side effect of Scala multiple inheritance in my admittedly limited experience. Thanks for the several solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a self type declaration on `OptionParser`. This will require types that mix in `OptionParser` to be an `App`, without mixing in `App` itself.

```
trait OptionParser { this: App =>

    def test(): Unit = {
        println("test")
        println(args)
    }

}

object Test extends App with OptionParser {
    test()
    println("done")
}
```

Comment: Didn't want to restrict to App extension but interesting.